# AngularJS - ngView scope?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using ngView's to load content on demand.
What I don't quite get is *when* is the controller for each view created?

I have the same controller assigned to a few of my views, and they seem to share data between them. yet my impression is that the controller is recreated each time the specific view is shown.

So how does it work?

Comment: What data are they sharing? `$scope.food="beans";` would of course be shared, but dynamic data is not innately shared.

Comment: Do you have any source? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

When you define a controller in your JavaScript using `.controller()`, you *defining a class*, not creating an instance of an object.

Colin Moock defines the difference this way: an *Object* is like an airplane, it can perform actions like `fly()` and has properties like `maxPassengers`. A *Class* is like the blueprint on how to build that airplane, from which you can make infinite airplanes. Amazing! You can watch Colin Moock's whole explanation right here if you want: http://tv.adobe.com/watch/colin-moocks-lost-actionscript-weekend/object-oriented-programming-overview/

Every time the view is loaded, a new Instance of your controller Class is created. Most Angular.js controllers have a capitalized name like `Dashboard` or `Contacts` because they describe a *Class.*

**So the answer to your question is a new instance of your controller is created every time your view loads.**

Comment: So how come I don't lose all state when swapping pages?

Comment: Because your state is recorded in your `$scope` variable which is an instance and doesn't get reinstated. `$scope` gets passed into the instance of your construction function when it runs.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that when using a factory for your model and injecting the model into the controller, then you can keep state when you change views.

I used a factory for one of my controllers and "new FooModel()" inside another controller, thus two different behaviors on the views using the two controllers.